# vertexshader / vertexprogram write vertex attributes to vbo?

Tags: opengl, directx, shader, vbo

Is there a way to alter vertex attributes in a vertexshader/vertexprogram and save the changes back into the VBO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is called Transform Feedback in OpenGL (or Stream-Out in DirectX):

- http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/transform_feedback.txt
- http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec42.core.20120119.pdf (page 158)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205121.aspx

Comment: hey and thanks! as i understand it, this will simply record whatever transformation is made by the vertex program, right? is there any way to decide within a vertex shader what and when to update? like if(condition){save UV coordinates in VBO}

Comment: No, it will map 1-to-1. For each vertex you pass in, it will store all (or some, but always same) varyings into output buffer.

Comment: is there any extension that allows to write specific data into the vbo? ARB_shader_image_load_store allows to write into image buffers. is it possible to map an image buffer onto the same memory as a (non interleaved) VBO?

Comment: Is it technically possible to use it for vertex animation calculations?